# Как поставить Цикл While c++

Tags: c++, while

> Я хочу сделать так что бы после того как пользователь ответил неправильно программа возвращалась к вопросу но так как я новичёк и не знаю как это сделать, помогите пожалуйста!

```
 cout << "You are Freddy Fazbear, and you currently got some nice little Freddy Fazbears, and you should make a party for them." << endl;
cout << "You need to pick a place to have fun, Bucket of Freddy Fazbear or Room for parties, what will you choose? " << endl;
getline(cin, d);
    if (d == "Room for parties")  
    {
        cout << "While you had fun more little Fazbears want to join, let them in? " << endl;
        cin >> d;
    
    if (d == "No")
    
        cout << "You don't let them in and upset Fazbears left you and found another place to have fun! GOOD ENDING" << endl;
    
    else if (d == "Yes")
           
        cout << "You let them in and they destroyed the room and you will get Fired... BAD ENDING " << endl;
    else
    while(d != "Room for parties")
    {
        cout << "You don't answered correctly! Try again!" << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Если вы хотите делать это

```
if (d == "No")    
    cout << "...\n";        
else if (d == "Yes")           
    cout << "...\n";
else 
{
    while(d != "Room for parties")       
         { cout << "...\n" ;}

    // and what would you like to do if d == "Room for parties
}
```

то это странное решение, но в любом случаи вам лучше ясно изложить что вы бы хотели делать (вместо содержания текстов, которые для вопроса не имеют значения)